# My discord bot is responding to commands in dms(Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So basically I have been working on a discord bot for about two weeks now and someone brought it to my attention that you can activate commands in dms, I don't want people to do that since it allows people with lower roles to ruin other servers, any solutions? Thank you in advanced(This is the first time I ask a question here so I'm not familiar with the format)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You haven't showed us any of your code...

Comment: “*it allows people with lower roles to ruin other servers*” Can you elaborate on this point? How exactly does accepting commands via a slightly different medium open an opportunity for “*[ruining]*” servers…? You should be designing your code such that it handles commands based on *who* is invoking them, not *how* they are being invoked - anything else is not proper security.

Comment: @esqew so what i mean is that some commands can only be run by administrators, such as the bot giving updated about crypto, only admins can run that specific command but people are abusing it in private messages

Comment: @Bonfire I haven't had any ideas on how to fix this, i read the docs and couldn't find a solution, apparently the discord bots respond do commands in dms by default

Comment: Well, what about the rest of your bot's code?

Comment: @Bonfire its mostly webs scraping using beautiful soup and uses googlesearch to get info on a topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another decorator to the commands funtion to set it guild only

Docs: [`commands.guild_only()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.guild_only)

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def cmd(ctx):
    ...
```

Comment: tysm it worked, ive been trying to fix this for over 3 hrs